# Code is not being updated through at AWS lambda function

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I get an error  when I update the code at AWS lambda function from my local machine. I  tried to reduce size of files but still has same issue. I am using react JS with node modules.

Here is the error log:

The deployment package of your Lambda function "project/function name" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function.[image]

Comment: [hephalump's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56506273/8016330) is correct. That is not an error but an informational message about the web console. If you want to modify the code and also run it quickly take a look at [SAM Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-reference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline code editor has a 3mb limit for editing code. This limit includes any dependencies, so if the total size of your deployment package is greater than 3mb you’ll need to edit your code locally, zip it, and upload it to either S3 or directly in the console.

You can read about Lambda limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).